# LESS variables doesn't apply

Tags: css, less

I new to LESS, first using it, but from the start have problem.
I can apply variables at all, here is photo with background-color http://i1367.photobucket.com/albums/r799/Yaroslav_Kuzyo/1_zps9e9436e1.jpg, as you can see Chrome cross background-colour, but if I use #HEX it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the compiler that are you using ?

Comment: please make JSfiddle instead of a picture

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load the .less file directly as your CSS. You need to either compile it into CSS and use that in your page, or use less.js to run it client-side.

Comment: it's my links for .less and js compiler <br/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.less"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="less-1.3.3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `link` `rel` attribute to `stylesheet/less` so that it can be parsed by the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, freejosh. Everything works fine )))))))